# User identification in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We are building a website which has a set of public pages, and private pages. For Web Analytics, we are using Google Analytics.
We have a unique `userId` which can identify the user once he login. So this takes care of the private pages in the site.
We have couple of questions related to the User identification.

1. For the public pages, since we do not have a userId, should we leave the `userId` property as empty?
2. Is there a way in which we can link the user's activity that happened between the private and public pages (assuming the cookies are there in the browser). Does GA rely on the clientId property to link it?
3. What is the recommended approach with respect to user id tracking when we have public and private pages in the same site?

Answer (score 0):

I answer the individual points below:

1. if you don't have a `userId` you shouldn't send the parameter, in this way you don't risk overwriting an empty value to the value (userId) associated with the user. If you can't avoid sending it, **its value must be `undefined`**.
2. send the `clientId` (and / or `userId`) as a user-level **custom dimension** (the cookie must be the same).
3. the same approach for which the `userId` is envisaged: if the user identifier is present then send it to google analytics, otherwise do not send the parameter (see point 1).

Comment: If userId is not there, does GA rely on the clientId and the _gid cookie value? 
Now after login we are sending the userId. So even if we don’t do the session merge, does GA know the two users (on with the cookie _gid and other with userId) same?

Comment: For session merge need that clientid (_ga cookie) is the same.